# neural network code explanation

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

The following is an implementation of a simple Perceptron supplied in [a blog](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/neural-networks-a-perceptron-in-matlab/).

```
input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
numIn = 4;
desired_out = [0;1;1;1];
bias = -1;
coeff = 0.7;
rand('state',sum(100*clock));
weights = -1*2.*rand(3,1);

iterations = 10;

for i = 1:iterations
     out = zeros(4,1);
     for j = 1:numIn
          y = bias*weights(1,1)+...
               input(j,1)*weights(2,1)+input(j,2)*weights(3,1);
          out(j) = 1/(1+exp(-y));
          delta = desired_out(j)-out(j);
          weights(1,1) = weights(1,1)+coeff*bias*delta;
          weights(2,1) = weights(2,1)+coeff*input(j,1)*delta;
          weights(3,1) = weights(3,1)+coeff*input(j,2)*delta;
     end
end
```

I have the following questions,

(1) which one is training data here?

(2) which one is test data here?

(3) which are the labels here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

training data is [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1] in the other view every row is one set of training data as follow

```
    >> input

input =

 0     0
 0     1
 1     0
 1     1
```

and target is

```
   desired_out =

 0
 1
 1
 1
```

please think about **desired_out this is your labels** .. **every row in training data(input) have a specific output(label) in binary set{0,1}(because this example for implementation of OR logic circuit.**

in matlab you can use or function as below for further understanding:

```
    >> or(0,0)

    ans =

        0

    >> or(1,0)

    ans =

        1

    >> or(0,1)

   ans =

       1

   >> or(1,1)

   ans =

       1
```

Note that your code has not any training test and this code just trying to get weights and other parameters of perceptron but you can add training test to your code by just little program

```
    NumDataTest  =  10 ;
    test=randi( [0 , 1] , [ NumDataTest , 2]) ...
       +(2*rand(NumDataTest,2)-1)/20;
```

so test data will be similar to below

```
     test =

    1.0048    1.0197
    0.0417    0.9864
   -0.0180    1.0358
    1.0052    1.0168
    1.0463    0.9881
    0.9787    0.0367
    0.9624   -0.0239
    0.0065    0.0404
    1.0085   -0.0109
   -0.0264    0.0429
```

for test this data you can use your own program by below code:

```
    for i=1:NumDataTest
        y = bias*weights(1,1)+test(i,1)*weights(2,1)+test(i,2)*weights(3,1);
        out(i) = 1/(1+exp(-y));
    end
```

and finally:

```
     table(test(:,1),test(:,2),out,'VariableNames',{'input1' 'input2' 'output'})
```

output is

```
         input1       input2       output 
        _________    _________    ________

          1.0048       1.0197     0.99994
          0.041677      0.98637     0.97668
         -0.017968       1.0358     0.97527
          1.0052       1.0168     0.99994
          1.0463      0.98814     0.99995
          0.97875     0.036674      0.9741
          0.96238    -0.023861     0.95926
          0.0064527     0.040392    0.095577
          1.0085    -0.010895     0.97118
         -0.026367     0.042854    0.080808
```

Code section:

```
    clc
    clear
    input = [0 0; 0 1; 1 0; 1 1];
    numIn = 4;
    desired_out = [0;1;1;1];
    bias = -1;
    coeff = 0.7;
    rand('state',sum(100*clock));
    weights = -1*2.*rand(3,1);

    iterations = 100;

    for i = 1:iterations
    out = zeros(4,1);
        for j = 1:numIn
           y = bias*weights(1,1)+input(j,1)*weights(2,1)+input(j,2)*weights (3,1);
           out(j) = 1/(1+exp(-y));
           delta = desired_out(j)-out(j);
           weights(1,1) = weights(1,1)+coeff*bias*delta;
           weights(2,1) = weights(2,1)+coeff*input(j,1)*delta;
           weights(3,1) = weights(3,1)+coeff*input(j,2)*delta;
        end
   end
   %% Test Section
   NumDataTest  =  10 ;
   test=randi( [0 , 1] , [ NumDataTest , 2]) ...
      +(2*rand(NumDataTest,2)-1)/20;
   for i=1:NumDataTest
       y = bias*weights(1,1)+test(i,1)*weights(2,1)+test(i,2)*weights(3,1);
       out(i) = 1/(1+exp(-y));
   end
    table(test(:,1),test(:,2),out,'VariableNames',{'input1' 'input2' 'output'})
```

I hope this helps and sorry for my English if it's bad

Comment: I have an additional question: this program is using training data with 2 features and 1 label. That is why it is possible to plot them in a 2D space and draw a decision boundary line. Right? But, what if there are more features? How do we draw the decision boundary for samples that have more than two features?

Comment: I think 2D space just for better understanding and if you have more than 2 features it's not good idea for plot decision boundary and better idea is answering to this question "my classifier how much good?"  you can use ROC plot in MATLAB for it and it uses from decision function.
so in this situation you have decision function but not good idea for plot because plot is for knowing that "my classifier how much good?"