# Perceptron code explanation

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

What is going on in the following code?

```
function [ errors sepplane ] = perceptron ( pclass , nclass)
    sepplane = rand ( 1 , columns ( pclass ) + 1 ) - 0.5;
    tset = [   ones ( rows ( pclass ), 1 )  pclass ; 
             - ones ( rows ( nclass ), 1 ) -nclass 
           ];
    i = 1;
    do
        misind = tset * sepplane ' < 0;
        correction = sum ( tset ( misind , :), 1 ) / sqrt ( i );
        sepplane = sepplane + correction;
        ++ i;
    until ( norm ( sepplane ) * 0.0005 ) - norm ( correction ) > 0 || i > 1000;

    errors = mean ( tset * sepplane ' < 0);
    dzeros = tvec ( tlab == 1 , :);
    dones = tvec ( tlab == 2 , :);
    perceptron ( dzeros , dones)
end
```

**(0) Why is this code so drastically different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41330397/159072)?**

(1) Why are positive and negative classes separately passed in the 1st place? Then what is the point of doing a classification?

(2) What is `sepplane`?

(3) What is `misind`?

(4) What is the rationale behind the calculation of `correction`?

Comment: Based on your last couple questions, I strongly suggest that you do some more background reading about perceptrons. The wikipedia page links to a [book chapter](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/chapter/K3.pdf) that looks useful. Once you understand the theory, this code is a straight forward implementation.

Comment: @Cecilia, yes. But, your answer just saved me almost 24 hours.

Comment: This isn't MATLAB code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(0) Why is this code so drastically different than the other one?

This perceptron can be modified to be multi-class. The other is strictly for binary classification.

(1) Why are positive and negative classes separately passed in the 1st place? Then what is the point of doing a classification?

This is the training step of the perceptron, so you need the positive and negative examples to learn the weights

(2) What is `sepplane`?

The separating hyperplane which the perceptron learns.

(3) What is `misind`?

Is 1 if the example was correctly classified, and -1 otherwise.

(4) What is the rationale behind the calculation of correction?

If I misclassify an example, I want to adjust the weights, so that it will be correctly classified next time I run it through the perceptron.